# Average interval between records

Tags: mysql

edit: I have a table with start and end time fields. I would group the intervals between the common hours. It's possible?

Assume this table:

```
time_begin time_end
07:00      18:00
09:00      12:00 (this interval is in the first line)
17:00      18:00 (this interval is in the first line)
```

I would like to return the lines:

```
time_begin time_end
09:00      12:00
17:00      18:00
```

Thanks

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do/requirements list.

Comment: I tried to better explain my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query.

```
SELECT time_begin, time_end
FROM table_name
WHERE time_begin < (SELECT time_end 
                    FROM table_name
                    LIMIT 1)
AND   time_begin > (SELECT time_begin
                    FROM table_name
                    LIMIT 1)
AND   time_end < (SELECT time_end
                    FROM table_name
                    LIMIT 1)
AND   time_end > (SELECT time_begin
                    FROM table_name
                    LIMIT 1)
```

This query returns all time intervals which are between the time interval in the first row.